# Grpc-java Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1

Tags: maven

I am unable to build pom.xml,for grpc-java example provided in the link below:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java

it gives me the following error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: linux
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.release: ubuntu
[INFO] os.detected.release.version: 14.04
[INFO] os.detected.release.like.ubuntu: true
[INFO] os.detected.release.like.debian: true
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: linux-x86_64
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building helloworld 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-protoc-plugin:0.4.3:compile (default) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 proto file(s) to /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/java
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-protoc-plugin:0.4.3:compile-custom (default) @ helloworld ---
[WARNING] Missing POM for io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:exe:linux-x86_64:0.8.0
[INFO] Compiling 1 proto file(s) to /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/src/main/resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[24,38] method marshaller in class io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils cannot be applied to given types;
  required: T
  found: com.google.protobuf.Parser<io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloRequest>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: com.google.protobuf.Parser<io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloRequest>
    bound(s): com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[25,38] method marshaller in class io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils cannot be applied to given types;
  required: T
  found: com.google.protobuf.Parser<io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloResponse>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: com.google.protobuf.Parser<io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloResponse>
    bound(s): com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[79,45] callOptions has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[79,11] channel has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[103,45] callOptions has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[103,11] channel has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[128,45] callOptions has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[128,11] channel has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[INFO] 8 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.203 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-22T09:25:43+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project helloworld: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[24,38] method marshaller in class io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: T
[ERROR] found: com.google.protobuf.Parser<io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloRequest>
[ERROR] reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
[ERROR] inferred: com.google.protobuf.Parser<io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloRequest>
[ERROR] bound(s): com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[25,38] method marshaller in class io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: T
[ERROR] found: com.google.protobuf.Parser<io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloResponse>
[ERROR] reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
[ERROR] inferred: com.google.protobuf.Parser<io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloResponse>
[ERROR] bound(s): com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[79,45] callOptions has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[79,11] channel has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[103,45] callOptions has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[103,11] channel has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[128,45] callOptions has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[ERROR] /home/pradnya/workspace/helloworld/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/GreeterGrpc.java:[128,11] channel has private access in io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.grpc.examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>helloworld</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-all</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <releases>
      <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Central Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
  </pluginRepository>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>protoc-plugin</id>
    <url>https://dl.bintray.com/sergei-ivanov/maven/</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <!--
          The version of protoc must match protobuf-java. If you don't depend on
          protobuf-java directly, you will be transitively depending on the
          protobuf-java version that grpc depends on.
        -->
        <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-beta-1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
        <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
        <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:0.8.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

want to build it using grpc-all 0.9.0 version explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is using the 0.8.0 gRPC code generator:

```
<pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
<pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:0.8.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
```

But the 0.9.0 library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-all</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

v0.8.0 was the last release that gRPC didn't provide any API guarantees. v0.9.0 onward we would expect an older code generator to be compatible (although maybe missing features/improvements) with newer gRPC runtime libraries.